# Only replace first matching element using PHP's mb_ereg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace only the first matching element in a string instead of replacing every matching element in a string

```
$str = 'abc abc abc';
$find = 'abc';
$replace = 'def';
echo mb_ereg_replace( $find, $replace, $str );
```

This will return "def def def".

What would I need to change in the $find or $replace parameter in order to get it to return "def abc abc"?

Comment: Will the first occurence always be at the start of the string? (I'm guessing not but it's worth a shot!)

Comment: Hey Andy, it may not be, it could be anywhere.

I was suspecting the find var could look something like this $find = '[abc]{1}';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very elegant, but you could try

```
$find = 'abc(.*)'; 
$replace = 'def\\1';
```

Note that if your `$find` contains more capturing groups, you need to adjust your `$replace`. Also, this will replace the first abc in every line. If your input contains several lines, use `[\d\D]`instead of `.`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do a [mb_strpos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php) for "abc",  then do [mb_substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)

eg

```
$str = 'blah abc abc blah abc';
$find = 'abc';
$replace = 'def';
$m  = mb_strpos($str,$find);
$newstring = mb_substr($str,$m,3) . "$replace" . mb_substr($str,$m+3);
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea.  Ideally I'd like to be able to edit the regex but this could do as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need fancy regex replacements, you're better off using plain old `str_replace`, which takes `$count` as fourth parameter:

```
$str = str_replace($find, $replace, $str, $count);
```

Comment: Hi, I do need fancy regex and it needs to support multi-byte as well.

Comment: Fair enough. I see a lot of people asking about using preg* functions when they don't need the complexity!

Comment: Isn't that incorrect? The fourth parameter is the number of time that the replace occurs.

Comment: @Mat - isn't that what my answer says?